# Why would /. Expand rather than replace an expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm using /., Simplify, FullSimplify, etc. to simplify complicated solutions to a system of differential equations. Part of this is replacing certain expressions by Greek letters, e.g., `BigExpr /. {Expr1-> G1, Expr2-> G2}` etc. This mostly works, but in my most recent attempt, two of three such replacements happened, but for the third, MMA instead expanded the sub-expression, which is this: `2 (d^2 + e^2) + 2 (d + e) p + p^2`. Rather than replace it by `G` (capital Greek gamma) as I instructed, MMA replaced it by `2 d^2 + 2 e^2 + 2 d p + 2 e p + p^2`wherever it appeared. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Edit your question to include the code (InputForm) for a concrete example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Most likely some kind of auto simplification is happening before the replace command. For a siple example, consider (e + p) + p /. {e + p -> g} which gives e+2p in contrast to (e + p) + 3 /. {e + p -> g} which gives 3+g. To get the replacement you want, look at the FullForm of the expression.

Comment: As a general rule, the LHS of a replacement rule should be kept as simple as possible. Using examples of @bills, `(e + p) + p /. {e -> g - p}` evaluates to `g + p` and `(e + p) + 3 /. {e -> g - p}` evaluates to `3 + g`. Alternatively, use `Simplify[(e + p) + p, g == e + p]` and `Simplify[(e + p) + 3, g == e + p]`